# What is the elegant way to perform multiple word searches in R?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, lapply

I'm building a word search game and am looking for an "R" way to do the last line of this reprex, which is trivial for 2 words, but I want it to handle **n** words.  I'm thinking that one of the `*apply` functions could work here, but somehow I can't work it out.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample word list (173,000 words in reality)
words <- data.frame(word = c('test', 'word', 'active', 'angina', 'endite', 'endive', 'engine', 'entire', 'alanine', 'evening', 'escape', 'entered'),
                    word_length = c(4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7))

# Find a 6 letter word with 2nd letter n and a 7 letter word with letters 4 and 6 n
find       <- '.n.... ...n.n.'
find_words <- unlist(str_split(find, ' '))
find_regex <- paste0('\\b', find_words, '\\b')

words %>%
    filter(word_length == nchar(find_words[1])) %>%
    filter(str_detect(word, find_regex[1])) %>%
    full_join(
        words %>%
            filter(word_length == nchar(find_words[2])) %>%
            filter(str_detect(word, find_regex[2]))
        , by = character(), suffix = c('1', '2')) %>%
    select(word1, word2)
```

A further question would be to do the same but where numbers represent the unknown letters as this reduces the matches significantly

```
# Find a 6 letter word with 2nd letter n and a 7 letter word with letters 4 and 6 n
# where the 1st and 6th letters of the first word and 1st and 3rd letters of the second word are all the same (1 in find)
# and the 4th letter of the first word matches the 5th letter of the second word (3 in find)

find <- c('1n2341', '151n3n6')

# "Manual" solution
words %>%
    filter(word_length == 6 & str_sub(word, 2, 2) == 'n') %>%
    full_join(words %>% filter(word_length == 7  & str_sub(word, 4, 4) == 'n' & str_sub(word, 6, 6) == 'n'),
              by = character(), suffix = c('1', '2')) %>%
    # match letter represented by '1'
    filter(str_sub(word1, 1, 1) == str_sub(word1, 6, 6)) %>%
    filter(str_sub(word1, 1, 1) == str_sub(word2, 1, 1)) %>%
    filter(str_sub(word1, 1, 1) == str_sub(word2, 3, 3)) %>%
    # match letter represented by '3'
    filter(str_sub(word1, 4, 4) == str_sub(word2, 5, 5)) %>%
    select(word1, word2)
```

Comment: For your further question, is it also a requirement that it generalize to many words, or is it only for pairs? And will it also be run on the large list with 200,000 words?

Comment: @Alexlok, yes it will be run on the full word list and ideally, I'd like it to be generalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you can simply use `lapply()` or `map()` to loop on the patterns. `str_detect()` is already vectorized for the string.

Then if you want to combine the entries into a new data frame, you can simply use `expand.grid()`, to reproduce your example. But note that this format may not the best, depending on what you want to do with it afterwards.

```
map(find_words, ~ words$word[str_detect(words$word, .x)]) %>%
  expand.grid()
#       Var1    Var2
# 1   angina alanine
# 2   endite alanine
# 3   endive alanine
# 4   engine alanine
# 5   entire alanine
# 6  entered alanine
# 7   angina evening
# 8   endite evening
# 9   endive evening
# 10  engine evening
# 11  entire evening
# 12 entered evening
```

---

For the further question, here is a solution in several steps, but that only works for 2 words (I use the first to create a pattern for the second). I think the performance should stay reasonably good for a larger set of words, but that requires testing.

```r
library(tidyverse)


words <- tibble(word = c('alanins', 'snoops', 'test', 'word', 'active', 'angina', 'endite', 'endive', 'engine', 'entire', 'alanine', 'evening', 'escape', 'entered'),
                    word_length = nchar(word))

pattern1 <- '1n2341'
pattern2 <- '151n3n6'

candidates1 <- words$word[words$word_length == nchar(pattern1)]

has_consistent_names <- function(vec){
  # TRUE if each name is associated with a single value
  map_lgl(names(vec),
          ~ length(unique(vec[names(vec) == .x])) == 1) %>%
    all()
}

candidates1_chars <- map(candidates1, ~ setNames(str_split(.x, "")[[1]],
                             str_split(pattern1, "")[[1]]))

candidates1_chars <- Filter(has_consistent_names, candidates1_chars)

candidates2 <- words$word[words$word_length == nchar(pattern2)]
pattern2_chars <- str_split(pattern2, "")[[1]]

build_regex <- function(xx, ptrn){
  # for xx a named dictionary of numbers to characters, make regex pattern
  xx <- xx[ptrn]
  xx[is.na(xx)] <- "."
  paste(xx, collapse="")
}

pattern2_regex <- map_chr(candidates1_chars,
                          ~ build_regex(.x, pattern2_chars))


tibble(word1 = map_chr(candidates1_chars, ~paste(.x, collapse="")),
       word2 = map(pattern2_regex, ~candidates2[str_detect(candidates2, .x)])) %>%
  unnest(word2)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   word1  word2  
#>   <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 angina alanins
#> 2 angina alanine
#> 3 endite evening
#> 4 endive evening
#> 5 engine evening
#> 6 entire evening
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The idea is relatively simple, but there are many practical issues to implement it: I first take all words that are the right length to match the first pattern (candidates1), then split by letter so that I can see if their own letters respect the pattern1 (i.e. in that example if the first and last characters are the same).

So I get this list of position <-> letter from the first word, and I use it to generate a regex pattern for the second word: I can use a named vector to easily convert between letter and character. If a number exists in the second word but not the first, I have a `NA`, that I can simply replace with `.` to match anything, and I can paste it all together.

Finally, all that is left is to test each candidate1 pattern on every actual word, to find the ones that match. I could use `map_chr()` if I always had exactly one match; in that example one pattern doesn't match, so I store the result as a list, ready for some post-processing (filter rows where length(word2) is 0, keep only the first element if length > 1, ...)

Comment: Thanks @Alexlok, that's great. It ran very quickly (a few seconds) on the full list and I think I can see a way to generalise it. 
It didn't filter only those words with 2nd letter n for the first word, but I added that to the filter for length. With that, it returned 54 rows from the full 200k list, with all but 7 having nothing in word2. Avoiding a loop, I can't work out how to filter these while maintaining the link to word1.  length works on the list items individually, but not en-masse.
For a more realistic result set, try adding to the words: "snoops", "alanins"

Comment: There are different ways to go about it, easiest is simply to use `unnest()` that does all the work (see my edit). Another solution to avoid more looping could be to change the last call `map(pattern2_regex, ~candidates2[str_detect(candidates2, .x)])` to use a dedicated function, and add a step to keep only the first match, then use `filter()` on the resulting dataframe to remove rows where `is.na(word2)`.

Comment: Thanks again @Alexlok, I've learned so many new things with this.